Troubles uploading to ESP32 with attached 3.3v lipo battery and battery maneger
I cant find the com port of my esp32 when connecting it with my PC. This happend after soldering a batterymanger and lipo battery onto the esp32. I have tried using an usb hub with an external powersuply of 5v and 2 ampre as i was getting power surge when connecting it directly to the pc. Still i cant upload.
I have tried using an usb hub with an external powersuply of 5v and 2 ampre as i was getting power surge on the com port when connecting it directly to the pc. Still i cant upload.
